# Cannot translate SQLDeveloper settings to JDBC url

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

So I can connect to an Oracle database through SQLDeveloper v3.2.20.09, but when I try to use those same settings in an JDBC URL I get the following error:

```
[LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; remaining name 'cn=SomeService,cn=OracleContext,dc=SomeDomain,dc=com'
```

My URL looks like this:

jdbc:oracle:thin:SomeUser/SomePassword@ldap://SomeHost:SomePort/SomeService,cn=OracleContext,dc=SomeDomain,dc=com

My SQLDeveloper Settings like something like:

```
Username: SomeUser
Password: SomePassword
Connection Type: LDAP
Role: Default
LDAP Server: SomeHost:3060:3131
Context: cn=OracleContext,dc=SomeDomain,dc=com
DB Service: SomeService
OS Authentication: false
Kerberos Authentication: false
Proxy Connection: false
```

So can someone help me translate these settings to a usable JDBC url?  If not what could be misconfigured?  I had this working, but then the DBA changed my user I use to access the DB and Java stopped working.  SQLDeveloper is working with the new settings.

Comment: IIRC, LDAP is different for JDBC, and your URL isn't how it's done. Let me see if I can find it.

Comment: And I think this is it? https://community.oracle.com/message/2741715

Comment: Previously I had it working through normal JDBC URLs using LDAP.  This has to be portable because my solution works for any JDBC database.  I need a portable URL.